# Make Visual Studio Code use WSL/bash in the debug console on Windows

Tags: bash, debugging, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Visual Studio Code on Windows, but run my (NodeJS/TypeScript) application on the WSL/bash. However, I can't make the VS Code Debug Console use bash. It seems to still use cmd.exe.

I can test this by running my application from inside Visual Studio Code, and then entering `process.platform` in the debug console. It shows `win32`.

On the other hand, the Terminal *does* use bash.exe.

I've set `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` and `terminal.external.windowsExec` to `C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe`.

How can I make VS Code use bash in the Debug Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the settings I mentioned have no effect. I just needed to add the `"useWSL": true` setting to my launch.json.

**Update**
I've switched to using the  [Remote Development extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) for VS Code. I've written about it [here](https://www.petermorlion.com/debugging-wsl-from-vs-code/).